# Is there a Tags Input component for Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm looking for a specific component for Angular, something that works in a similar way of  [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Can anyone help me finding a out-of-the-box component or providing some example of implementation? I need it for Angular 4

Comment: ✔ [Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#angular) is awesome!

Comment: MatChips is great also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after i search again and again finally i find this component and it works with me
it looks like  `MatChipsModule` that used in angular material with some cool features    [ngx-chips](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips)

Comment: sadly, it has its bugs and its not mantained since a long time ago.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR** In Angular, that type of component is named *chip*. Change your keyword and you will find better results.

---

There are many ways to reach it, the most common is through Angular Material.

Firstly, install Angular Material in your project following the [official tutorial](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started). Luckily it is well written and I don't think you are going to have problems.

Then, import *MatChipsModule* in the component you want to see the tags, in this way:

```
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material';
```

and finally you can use the component in your template:

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let i of items" [selectable]="selectable"
           [removable]="removable" (remove)="remove(i)">
    {{i.tagName}}
    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Source: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview

Comment: thank you cristian but unfortunately i don't use angular material and i can't use it in this project  so i will be thankful if you have another solution

Comment: if you can't use any external module then you have no many ways, you have to create it by yourself

Comment: i already use external modules but i need that tags to finish my project so i think it will be bad to include angular material for that purpose only as i'll not use it in any thing else

Comment: Luckily angular material is modular so you don't need to import the whole framework but only the piece you need :) just the essential

Comment: Don't mistake UI terminology for framework terminology. People might be using Angular but not Material. And "chip" is a name coming from Material UI, not from Angular, the application framework.